# Create shared_lock or unique_lock based on a condition

Tags: c++, locking

I need to create unique_lock or shared lock based on a parameter in my function. I couldn't define properly in the scope of function. So I need to do something like this.

```
function (bool check) {
 lock;
 if (check) {
  lock = std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>(mutex);
 } else {
  lock = std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>(mutex);
 }
 lock.lock();
 doTask....
```

Comment: You can make `doTask....` a function and then call that function in each branch

Comment: So what I am trying to do is, if check is true only one thread can do the task otherwise every thread can do the task. This is why I want to create  a shared lock. So every thread can access to a resource (a vector in my case)

Comment: All threads try to modify a vector, but the lock type is sent by the client so I need to create a lock based on the value of this boolean parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver I also couldn't see any other option. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
void function (bool check) {
  std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> u(mutex, std::defer_lock);
  std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> s(mutex, std::defer_lock);
  if (check) {
    u.lock();
  } else {
    s.lock();
  }
  doTask....
```

Comment: u.lock is valid only within the if scope, it wont lock the entire function

Comment: @AhmetTanakol No. `u.lock();` is a function call. It doesn't construct anything that goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since the caller is passing in the `check` condition anyway, you could give your `function` a template parameter to let the caller specify which type of lock to use, eg:

```
template<typename LockClass>
function () {
 LockClass<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex);
 doTask....
}
```

```
//function (true);
function<std::unique_lock>();
```

```
//function (false);
function<std::shared_lock>();
```

Otherwise, you could split your code into multiple functions:

```
doTask() {
  ...
}

unique_function () {
  std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex);
  doTask();
}

shared_function () {
  std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex);
  doTask();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed the change function parameters or split the code into multiple functions

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
void function (bool check)
{
 std::variant<std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>, std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>> lock;
 if (check) {
 lock = std::unique_lock(mut);
 } else {
 lock = std::shared_lock(mut);
 }
 //doTask...
}
```